# Не получается сохранять по уникальному внешнему ключу

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Привет. В общем, есть модель:

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    seo_name = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
     vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, unique=False, blank=True, default=None, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Делаю парсинг xml файла и в этом файле vendor указан в каждой позиции, мне надо что бы в модель vendor сохранялись только уникальные значения, а каждому продукту указывался cвой vendor, я делаю так:

```
for p in products:
    vendor = Vendor()
    vendor.name = p['vendor']
    try:
        vendor.save()
    except:
        pass
    product.vendor = vendor
```

В итоге получается что в модели Product vendor присвоен только тем значениям в момент парсинга которых их vendor еще не был сохранен. 
Вопрос в том, как сделать так, что бы vendor присваивался каждому product?

Для тех кто сюда придет из интернетов, вот решение : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386114/i-cant-save-uniq-value-in-foreign-key/36386319?noredirect=1#comment60389482_36386319

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) метод для `vendor`:

```py
for p in products:
    product = Product()
    # ...

    vendor, _ = Vendor.objects.get_or_create(name=p['vendor'])
    product.vendor = vendor  # or product.vendor_id = vendor.id   

    product.shop = shop_name
    product.description = p['description']
    product.save()
```

ответ [@alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36386319)